# MySql как разделить таблицу на группы, по значению столбца?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

Существует MySQL таблица подобного вида (упрощено):

```
User:
  UserID

Group:
  GroupID

Membership:
  GroupID
  UserID
```

Все просто, 1 таблица отвечает за пользователей, 2 за проходящие события, и 3 за участников различных событий. PrimalKey 3 таблицы (GroupID, UserID).

Когда таблица заполнена, она выглядит примерно так:

```
group_id user_id
0        2
0        5
0        8
1        7
1        9
...
```

Я смотрю на это с точки зрения оптимизации. Есть ли возможность создать разбиение по group_id, чтобы оптимизировать все действия с таблицей? Я пытался сделать это используя Hash критерий, однако, дело в том, что я не знаю сколько может существовать групп, а стандартное разделение требует фиксированный размер. В конечном итоге хотелось бы получить что-то такое:

```
p0
group_id user_id
0        2
0        5
0        8
...
p1
group_id user_id
1        7
1        9
...
```

Или в данном случае мне под каждый group_id создавать свою таблицу?

Comment: А чем обычный SELECT запрос в данном случае не устраивает? Настройте нормально индексацию и все должно быть быстро

Comment: Просто сделайте индекс по полю `group_id` и все операции с выборкой/сортировкой/группировкой по `group_id` должны быстро тогда работать.